# Laravel route in multiple middelwares

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-middleware

I want to have the same route within the `auth:api` middleware, and also out of it.

Right now, if I include it in both, only the one out of the `auth:api` is taken into consideration, even if the user is logged in.

Is there a way that if the user is logged in it goes to `auth:api` and if not it goes out of any middleware?

The reason to do this is that if the user is logged in, I want to access user information, and for that it needs to go through the `auth:api`.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Can you also add the code for the Route and Controller method?

Comment: Hi  @RossWilson, I'm using Laravel 5.5. In the api.php I've got a route like `Route::post('/lastComments', 'MainController@getLastComments');` which I want it go through the auth:api if the user is logged in (acces token sent) and through no middleware in any other case

Comment: Are you using Laravel passport?

Comment: Yes Ross, I am, that's why even if you are logged in, if you don't go through the `auth:api` middleware, you don't have access to the user object. It's not like if you are in a web route, where you could then go and run `Auth::check()` in the controller... So that's why I wanted the route to go in both places in and out of the `auth:api`middleware. As a workaround, I've created 2 different routes pointing to the same controller function, and then I check in the controller if the user object exist or not. But this has forced me add extra logic in the frontend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you're including the token in the request, you will be able to get access to the current `User`.

Out-of-the-box, Laravel will set the default guard to be `web`. When you place routes under the `auth` middleware it will set the default guard to be whatever is passed to the middleware i.e. when you have `auth:api` it will set the default guard to be `api` for that request.

If you want to be able to access the `User` without it being under the `auth:api` middleware, you will simply need to be explicit with what guard should be used e.g.

```
auth('api')->user(); // or Auth::guard('api')->user();
```

The same applies for `check()`:

```
auth('api')->check(); // or Auth::guard('api')->check();
```

or if you're using the `Request` object:

```
$request->user('api'); // or request()->user('api');
```

Answer (score -1):

It 's not possible to have multiple same routes in your application and work independently. Laravel will match the first one that it find in your routes map.

Create one route and check for authentication in your controller.

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    // The user is logged in...
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't work as you need it to be in the auth:api middleware to get the user info.